# How to see which peers endorsed a transaction in hyperledger Fabric using Java SDK?

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am studying and running samples from the **Hyperledger Fabric** samples .

According to my understanding :-

**Endorsement policies define which peers need to agree on the results of a transaction before it can be added to the ledger.**

We can define this policy in our client code during chaincode instantiation.

(Is endorsement applied during query proposal as well or only during transaction/invoke proposal ?)

**Currently i am running the Build your First Network n/w from the Fabric samples and using Fabric Java SDK.**   http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.0/build_network.html

My question is how to check using Fabric Java SDK , **which peers** are endorsing the transaction , the **number of endorsers** ? i.e how to check if the endorsement is working properly .

Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it ! **TransactionActionInfo** class from the Java SDK has endorsers and endorsement count .